# Safety in Vienna and budapest

Tags: vienna, budapest

I am planning to make a short trip to Vienna and Budapest. I want to know how safe is it for brown tourists. I know in general these are very safe cities but I would like to know it from my perspective. My husband and I travelled to Prague and we faced two incidents which I guess we're racist in nature. The whole trip was nice except these two incidents but I am a little scared as this time I will be travelling alone. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.